# Adding rows and columns to an HTML table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jquery to dynamically add columns and rows to the table.

The problem I'm having is that I'm adding the rows with code as below:

```
        $('#colorgrid').append("<tr id='Row2' class='input-row'><td><input type='text' name='shade' placeholder='shade'/></td><td ><input type='checkbox' name='asdf'/></td><td ><input type='checkbox' name='shade'/></td><td ><input type='checkbox' name='color'/></td></tr>")
```

So after I add one column and then add one row, it is missing a checkbox. Please see screen shot below:

Ideally whenever new row is added I would like it to fill however many columns there are with checkboxes and fill the `name` attribute of the checkboxes with the column name.

**Question**

How can I add a new row such a way so that it is really dynamic and I'm not hardcoding the contents of the row. It should fill all the columns with checkboxes and name them corresponding to the columnheader.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andy's answer is cleaner and you may want to do that while modifying the elements within it. However if it's less a case of "copy but different" and more "new row with certain parts copied", [this fork might help](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/MMmQc/).

The technique here involves creating a new row, then iterating through each of the desired table headers with [jQuery's each method](http://api.jquery.com/each/) (specified here to select `#Row1 th:not(.space)` within the table, ie "the headers in `#Row1` that aren't `.space`"), using [jQuery's trim](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to get their inner text devoid of superfluous whitespace (newlines, indentation), and then appending a new cell and input with that value as a name for each.

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [JQuery's Clone function](http://api.jquery.com/clone/). You can clone the last or first row without actually hard-coding the elements that you will add. This will copy all the elements including the new column(s).

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>

$('.hello').clone().appendTo('.container');
```

this should produce

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
</div>
```

It is up to you to modify the `name`, `id` and `value` of each element (if needed) before doing the `appendTo`. You can use jQuery with that as well. To find each `input` element:

```
newRow.find('input').each(function () {
    var $inputElem = $(this);
    $inputElem.attr('id', 'newId'); //change this to something more dynamic
    $inputElem.attr('name', 'newName'); //change this to something more dynamic
}
```